# File name not handled correctly in /foreach loop

Tags: loops, filesystem-access

For some reason when I try to specify a file name for \includegraphics in a loop, either using \foreach or using \clist, I get a file not found error. The error displays a valid path for the file, and if I use function parameter instead of trying to loop through a list it works right. There seems to be some issue with using loops and specifying files. How do I get this to generate usable file paths?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\lmrf}[3]
{
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \foreach \f in {#1}
    {
         \includegraphics{./Figures/\f}
    }
    \caption{#2}
    \label{fig:#3}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\lmrf{SURF1.png,SURF2.png}{(left) (right)}{rates}

\end{document}
```

This returns the error "! LaTeX Error: File `./Figures/SURF1.png' not found."
./Figures/SURF1.png is a file that is in that path. It works fine if I get rid of the loop.

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\lmrf}[3]
{
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{./Figures/#1}
    \caption{#2}
    \label{fig:#3}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\lmrf{SURF1.png}{(left) (right)}{rates}

\end{document}
```

Update:
Seems there's some underlying issue with resolving file names and loops. If I don't specify a path, it works. If I don't specify a file extension, it works. But, if a full path and file name including extension are specified it won't work.

Simply changing to:

```
\lmrf{SURF1,SURF2}{(left) (right) }{rates}
```

resulted in finding the files properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're primary mistake is in  the syntax of the `\foreach` group.  It should be:

```
\foreach <var> in {<list>}
{<action>}
```

I used your earlier example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\lmrf}[3]
{
 \begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \foreach \f/\r in {#1}
  {%%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth,keepaspectratio=true,angle=\r]{\f}%%{./Figures/\f};
  }%%
 \caption{#2}
 \label{fig:#3}
 \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\lmrf{example-image-a/30,example-image-b}{Caption}{Figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used your code:

```
 \foreach \f/\r in {#1}
  {%%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth,keepaspectratio=true,angle=\r]{./Figures/\f};%%
  }%%
```

and called it successfully with

```
\lmrf{restaurant/30,oak_tree/-10}{Caption}{Figure}
```

But

```
\lmrf{restaurant.png/30,oak_tree.png/-10}{Caption}{Figure}
```

I would suggest removing the `png` suffix:

[image]

Comment: That worked because the ./Figure/ part of the path was removed. It's not a compound statement being looped over, {} isn't needed. I'd like the figures in a static location.

Comment: @Eric I created the same sort of directory structure as you have and I get a successful run.  The difference I have is that I don't use the `png` suffix as it appears you do.  Remove the `png` and all should be good.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
\foreach \f in {<list>} <code>;
```

only works in the context of a Ti*k*Z picture (and not even always).

The generally correct code is

```
\foreach \f in {<list>} {<code>}
```

On the other hand, I'm not sure that you gain that much with such code obfuscation. Typing

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics{./Figures/SURF1}%
\includegraphics{./Figures/SURF2}

\caption{(left) (right)}
\label{fig:rates}
\end{figure}
```

doesn't seem so burdensome. If you have several of these constructs, it *might be useful to have an abbreviation, but in that case the `[H]` option will most likely be of a hindrance, rather than help.

A reduced version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\insertfigures}[1]{%
  \foreach \f in {#1}{\includegraphics{./Figures/\f}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\insertfigures{SURF1,SURF2}

\caption{(left) (right)}\label{rates}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This keeps `\caption` and `\label` searchable.

A more flexible implementation with key-value syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { eric/lmrf }
 {
  pos     .tl_set:N = \l_eric_lmrf_pos_tl,
  pos     .initial:n = htp,
  caption .tl_set:N = \l_eric_lmrf_caption_tl,
  label   .tl_set:N = \l_eric_lmrf_label_tl,
  path    .tl_set:N = \l_eric_lmrf_path_tl,
  o       .tl_set:N = \l_eric_lmrf_option_tl,
  f       .code:n =
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_eric_lmrf_images_seq { #1 }
    \seq_put_right:NV \l_eric_lmrf_options_seq \l_eric_lmrf_option_tl
   },
 }
\seq_new:N \l_eric_lmrf_images_seq
\seq_new:N \l_eric_lmrf_options_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\lmrf}{m}
 {
  \use:x { \exp_not:N \begin{figure}[\l_eric_lmrf_pos_tl] }
  \keys_set:nn { eric/lmrf } { #1 }
  \centering
  \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_eric_lmrf_images_seq }
   {
    \use:x
     {
      \exp_not:N \includegraphics
       [ \seq_item:Nn \l_eric_lmrf_options_seq { ##1 } ]
       { \l_eric_lmrf_path_tl \seq_item:Nn \l_eric_lmrf_images_seq { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  \caption{\tl_use:N \l_eric_lmrf_caption_tl}
  \label{\tl_use:N \l_eric_lmrf_label_tl}
  \end{figure}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\lmrfsetup}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { eric/lmrf } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%\lmfrsetup{./Figures/}

\begin{document}

\lmrf{
  caption={(left) (right)},
  label=rates,
%  path=./Figures/
  o = {width=3cm},
  f = example-image,
  f = example-image-a
}

\lmrf{
  caption={(left) (center) (right)},
  label=foo,
%  path=./Figures/
  o = {width=3cm},
  f = example-image,
  f = example-image-a,
  o = {width=2cm},
  f = example-image-b
}

\end{document}
```

The defined keys are `caption`, `label`, `pos`, `path,`o`and`f`. The first two should be self-explanatory;`pos`(default value`htp`) is for the positioning argument to`figure`.

With `o` you can specify options to `\includegraphics`. Until countermanded by another `o` key, the option will be set for all the following images, as shown in the second example.

The `path` key is for specifying the path for the images. You can also specify it in the preamble with `\lmfrsetup`, say

```
\lmfrsetup{path=./Figures/}
```

as shown. In this case you don't need to specify the key in the `\lmfr` command. I commented out all calls just because I was lazy to make a directory structure.

[image]

Comment: This looks like it could be a very useful response. I'm trying to standardize the way graphics are displayed in a collaborative document using submissions by multiple authors.